# How to use tkinter "moveto" to move an image to a position x,y

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

How to move an image to a position `x,y` ?

I am trying to move an image using "moveto" to cover a similar sized image.
The image is centered on a position `x,y`.
"moveto" places the top left hand corner of the image at `x,y`.
Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: If you know the size of the image, you can easily calculate `(tx, ty)` (coordinate of the top-left corner of the image so that the center of the image is at `(x, y)`.

Comment: @acw1668 isn't it possible to simply `anchor='c'`?

Comment: @Matiiss There is no `anchor` option for `Canvas.moveto()`.

Comment: @acw1668 when using `.create_image()` you can specify `anchor='c'`, wouldn't that affect how the image is positioned later on when for example moving it?

Comment: @Matiiss The answer is no.  You can try it yourself.

Comment: @acw1668 tried, you were right, btw is there a difference between `.moveto()` and `.coords()`? because `.coords()` seems to keep the anchor (I guess that is one difference but otherwise?)

Comment: @Matiiss The use of `.coords()` depends on what canvas item is applied.  For image item, it requires 2 arguments (other than the item ID).  But for rectangle or oval item, it requires 4 arguments.  Yes for OP case, it is easier to use `coords()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows what you've tried. Your question is unclear since `moveto` is documented.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution to my question.  Use use bbox to find the coordinates to which the image should be moved.
coords = self.w.bbox(image2[8])
self.w.moveto(image1[0],coords[0],coords[1])